# Unity: How to fix Error CS0201? new objects expression cant be used as a statement

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

How do I fix this problem when trying to run 2 different functions that do similar things? Both initialise a counter at 0 and then update based on an onmousedown script on a 3D object.

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> targets;
    public TextMeshProUGUI mistakeText;
    public TextMeshProUGUI QAText;
    public int question;
    public int mistakes;
    void Start()

    {

        mistakes = 0;
        mistakeText.text = "Mistakes: " + mistakes;



        question = 0;
        QAText.text = "Question: " + question; " /10";
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void UpdateMistakes(int mistakesToAdd)
    {
        mistakes += mistakesToAdd;
        mistakeText.text = "Mistakes: " + mistakes;
    }


    public void UpdateQuestion(int questionToAdd)
    {
        question += questionToAdd;
        QAText.text = "Question: " + question; "/10";
    }
}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2uti.jpg)

Comment: `"Question: " + question; " /10";` - look at this very closely

Comment: I did that because visual studio told me to. when i do without it it says } expected right there. How do i allow for text after the increment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorrect syntax for string concatination:

```
"Question: " + question; " /10";
```

->

```
"Question: " + question + " /10";
```

Comment: Thankyou! I now recieve the error Object reference not set to an instance of an object on line 23?

Comment: Because you haven't assigned `QAText` to an object in the Unity inspector.